# group lines by a certain count in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I'm trying to group results by a certain number in sql. i.e. if I have 60 lines and I want to group by groups of ten, I will have six groups of ten lines in them, reflecting the current order of the results in the table (in each group I will have the total or average of the lines in that group). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you please prepare an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MS SQL** ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d45c8/1/0)):

```
WITH cte(groupNumber, Id) AS
(
  SELECT
    (ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( ORDER BY Id )) / 10 AS groupNumber,
    Id
  FROM
    MyTable
)
SELECT
  MAX( Id ),
  groupNumber
FROM
  cte
GROUP BY
  groupNumber;
```

**MySQL** ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d45c8/33/0)):

```
SELECT
  MAX( Id ),
  groupNumber
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Id,
      CAST( FLOOR( (@a := @a + 1 ) / 10 ) AS UNSIGNED ) AS groupNumber
    FROM
      MyTable
    ORDER BY
      Id
  ) AS tmp,
  (SELECT @a := 0) r
GROUP BY
  groupNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

1. One query to find the count of results.
2. The selecting query would have the (rownumber % count) as a value so that all rows with same remainder will be in one group.

Comment: This sounds good, but how do I write the query for this? It will be something like
SELECT SUM(*) from `BLA` WHERE (rownumber % count = ???)

Answer (score -1):

Take   [a look to this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). When stack with mysql issues first you can use this site.